# Is there a shortcut in gedit to insert a line, i.e. the exact opposite of deleting a line?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gedit

In [`gedit`](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> deletes a line.

Is there a shortcut for inserting/adding a line?

Comment: There is a plugin called snippets that allows you to insert common text like code syntax using tab completion, if you are looking for something like that.

Comment: I have no idea what geany does. Maybe you should update your post as requested and include what the newline should consist off. Either you insert an empty line as in my answer, or you insert something specific from the cut buffer with Ctrl+V. If you want the latter you should write that in your question.

Comment: @Anthon Actually, to be honest, this whole question is bit stupid, had a little/huge brain freeze. So I flagged it for moderator attention to have it removed. I do appreciate your reply though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>End</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> will insert a line after the current one. You can use <kbd>Home</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to insert before the current line